# How to get the Index of an element in a list, by not using "list comprehensions"?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, indexing, list-comprehension

I'm new in haskell programming and I try to solve a problem by/not using list comprehensions.

The Problem is to find the index of an element in a list and return a list of the indexes (where the elements in the list was found.)

I already solved the problem by using list comprehensions but now i have some problems to solve the problem without using list comprehensions.

On my recursive way:

I tried to zip a list of `[0..(length list)]` and the list as it self.
then if the element  a  equals an element in the list -> make a new list with the first element of the Tupel of the zipped `list(my index)` and after that search the function on a recursive way until the list is [].

That's my list comprehension (works):

```
positions :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
positions a list = [x | (x,y) <- zip [0..(length list)] list, a == y]
```

That's my recursive way (not working):

```
positions' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
positions' _ [] = []
positions' a (x:xs) =
    let ((n,m):ns) = zip [0..(length (x:xs))] (x:xs)
    in if (a == m) then n:(positions' a xs)
       else (positions' a xs)
```

*sorry I don't know how to highlight words

but ghci says:

```
*Main> positions' 2 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9,2]
[0,0]
```

and it should be like that (my list comprehension):

```
*Main> positions 2 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9,2]
[1,10]
```

Where is my mistake ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is simply that when you say:

```
let ((n,m):ns) = zip [0..(length (x:xs))] (x:xs)
```

then `n` will always be `0`. That's because you are matching `(n,m)` against the first element of `zip [0..(length (x:xs))] (x:xs)`, which will necessarily always be `(0,x)`.

That's not a problem in itself - but it does mean you have to handle the recursive step properly. The way you have it now, `positions _ _`, if non-empty, will *always* have `0` as its first element, because the only way you allow it to find a match is if it's at the head of the list, resulting in an index of `0`. That means that your result will always be a list of the correct length, but with all elements `0` - as you're seeing.

The problem isn't with your recursion scheme though, it's to do with the fact that you're not modifying the result to account for the fact that you don't always want `0` added to the front of the result list. Since each recursive call just adds 1 to the index you want to find, all you need to do is `map` the increment function `(+1)` over the recursive result:

```
positions' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
positions' _ [] = []
positions' a (x:xs) =
    let ((0,m):ns) = zip [0..(length (x:xs))] (x:xs)
    in if (a == m) then 0:(map (+1) (positions' a xs))
       else (map (+1) (positions' a xs))
```

(Note that I've changed your `let` to be explicit that `n` will always be `0` - I prefer to be explicit this way but this in itself doesn't change the output.) Since `m` is always bound to `x` and `ns` isn't used at all, we can elide the let, inlining the definition of `m`:

```
positions' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
positions' _ [] = []
positions' a (x:xs) =
    if a == x
    then 0 : map (+1) (positions' a xs)
    else     map (+1) (positions' a xs)
```

You could go on to factor out the repeated `map (+1) (positions' a xs)` if you wanted to.

Incidentally, you didn't need explicit recursion to avoid a list comprehension here. For one, list comprehensions are basically a replacement for uses of `map` and `filter`. I was going to write this out explicitly, but I see @WillemVanOnsem has given this as an answer so I will simply refer you to his answer.

Another way, although perhaps not acceptable if you were asked to implement this yourself, would be to just use the built-in [elemIndices](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:elemIndices) function, which does exactly what you are trying to implement here.

Comment: Why is there still a zip at all in this implementation?

Comment: That's a good point @amalloy :) I just concentrated on explaining why the implementation in the OP didn't work, and how to fix it. And then went on to briefly mention easier ways to do it. And yes, I totally missed that the correction made `zip` completely unnecessary!

Comment: After my list comprehension worked, i thought about to make it with zip in recursive way as well. At first i didn't thought about a faster runtime or anything like that, i just want to improve my skills by working with haskell. I guess it's  good to program the same programs in different ways. In additon you guys taught me a lot of new commands and the reaction of haskell. I'm really thankful! :)

Answer (score 5):

We can make use of a [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) and [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) approach, like:

```
positions  :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
positions x = map fst . filter ((x ==) . snd) . zip [0..]
```

We thus first construct tuples of the form `(i, yi)`, next we filter such that we only retain these tuples for which `x == yi`, and finally we fetch the first item of these tuples.

For example:

```
Prelude> positions 'o' "foobaraboof" 
[1,2,8,9]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your

```
    let ((n,m):ns) = zip [0..(length (x:xs))] (x:xs)
```

is equivalent to

```
== {- by laziness -}
    let ((n,m):ns) = zip [0..] (x:xs)
== {- by definition of zip -}
    let ((n,m):ns) = (0,x) : zip [1..] xs
== {- by pattern matching -}
    let {(n,m)     = (0,x)
        ;      ns  =         zip [1..] xs }
== {- by pattern matching -}
    let { n        =  0
        ;   m      =    x
        ;      ns  =         zip [1..] xs }
```

but you never reference `ns`! So we don't need its binding at all:

```
positions' a (x:xs) =
    let { n = 0  ;  m = x } in
    if (a == m) then n : (positions' a xs)
                else     (positions' a xs)
```

and so, by substitution, you actually have

```
positions' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
positions' _ [] = []
positions' a (x:xs) =
    if (a == x) then 0 : (positions' a xs)      -- NB: 0 
                else     (positions' a xs)
```

And this is why all you ever produce are `0`s. But you want to produce the correct index: `0, 1, 2, 3, ...`.

First, let's tweak your code a little bit further into

```
positions' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
positions' a  =  go xs
  where
  go  []  = []
  go (x:xs) | a == x    =  0 : go xs            -- NB: 0 
            | otherwise =      go xs
```

This is known as a worker/wrapper transform. `go` is a worker, `positions'` is a wrapper. There's no need to pass `a` around from call to call, it doesn't change, and we have access to it anyway. It is in the *enclosing scope* with respect to the *inner* function, `go`. We've also used *guards* instead of the more verbose and less visually apparent `if ... then ... else`.

Now we just need to use something -- the correct index value -- instead of 0.

To use it, we must have it first. What is it? It starts as 0, then it is incremented on each step along the input list.

When do we make a step along the input list? At the recursive call:

```
positions' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
positions' a  =  go xs 0
  where
  go  []    _ = []
  go (x:xs) i | a == x    =  0 : go xs (i+1)    -- NB: 0 
              | otherwise =      go xs (i+1)
```

`_` as a pattern means we don't care about the argument's value -- it's there but we're not going to use it.

Now all that's left for us to do is to use that `i` in place of that `0`.